# MERGE command with multiple rows to insert or update

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, merge, insert-update

I have an XML like this:

```
<Job>
<Piece PieceID="0001">
  <OperatorID>O1</OperatorID>
  <MachineID>M1</MachineID>
<Status>OK</Status>
</Piece>
<Piece PieceID="0002">
  <OperatorID>O1</OperatorID>
  <MachineID>M1</MachineID>
<Status>ERROR</Status>
</Piece>
</Job>
```

This XML is passed via an XML type parameter into a stored procedure which parses it and stores the values in separate columns in a table - `PieceID, OperatorID, MachineID, Status` being the columns.

This stored procedure has to insert each piece if it doesn't exist or update if the piece is already present in table `X`. In the example above, once the operator fixes the error in the machine and reruns the job, the status might come in as OK for `PieceID 0002`. In that case, `PieceID=0001` should be ignored.

I know how do to this if there is only piece to process (`MERGE` command in SQL Server 2008?); I'm not able to get my head around doing this for several hundred pieces efficiently.

Please suggest an efficient approach for this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MERGE to update batches of data, not just single rows:

```
MERGE [TargetTable]
USING [SourceTable]
ON [TargetTable].PieceId= [SourceTable].PieceId
WHEN MATCHED AND status <> [SourceTable].Status THEN
UPDATE SET status = [SourceTable].Status
```

And you can use an INSERT for the new data, e.g.

```
INSERT ..... WHERE PieceId NOT IN (SELECT PieceId FROM targetTable)
```